# Creating a hijri datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am trying to create a jquery datepicker for islamic date. But i lack knowledge in jquery.  Any help on how to connect the picker and display it in the textfield?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.calendars.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.calendars.plus.js"></script>
  <script>
(function ($) {
    $.calendars.calendars.ummalqura.prototype.regionalOptions['ar'] = {
        name: 'UmmAlQura', // The calendar name
        epochs: ['BAM', 'AM'],
        monthNames: ['المحرّم', 'صفر', 'ربيع الأول', 'ربيع الثاني', 'جمادى الاول', 'جمادى الآخر', 'رجب', 'شعبان', 'رمضان', 'شوّال', 'ذو القعدة', 'ذو الحجة'],
        monthNamesShort: ['المحرّم', 'صفر', 'ربيع الأول', 'ربيع الثاني', 'جمادى الاول', 'جمادى الآخر', 'رجب', 'شعبان', 'رمضان', 'شوّال', 'ذو القعدة', 'ذو الحجة'],
        dayNames: ['الأحد', 'الإثنين', 'الثلاثاء', 'الأربعاء', 'الخميس', 'الجمعة', 'السبت'],
        dayNamesMin: ['الأحد', 'الإثنين', 'الثلاثاء', 'الأربعاء', 'الخميس', 'الجمعة', 'السبت'],
        dayNamesShort: ['الأحد', 'الإثنين', 'الثلاثاء', 'الأربعاء', 'الخميس', 'الجمعة', 'السبت'],
        digits: $.calendars.substituteDigits(['٠', '١', '٢', '٣', '٤', '٥', '٦', '٧', '٨', '٩']),
        dateFormat: 'yyyy/mm/dd', // See format options on BaseCalendar.formatDate
        firstDay: 6, // The first day of the week, Sat = 0, Sun = 1, ...
        isRTL: true // True if right-to-left language, false if left-to-right
    };
})(jQuery);
/*
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });*/
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to apologize as my answer perhaps not of the best quality (I don't have experience with islamic dates, but in my defense - I had experience with localization of jQueryUI.datepicker to Russian calendar)

So here it is:

First of all, please visit this page:
http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization

From the drop-down list near words 'Select a date from a popup or inline calendar' - chose 'Arabic'. If functionality that it provides out-of box is ok for your goal - then perhaps I could give some instructions how to install it. ^_^ If islamic dates require more tweaks and complex rules - then my answer would be useless.

To do what you asked, you MUST connect there libraries in your page in this order:

1. jQuery
2. jQuertUI
3. http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/datepicker-ar.js
   (you can follow a link and watch it's contents to learn and tweak it)

after that you can use arabic localization. You invoke it in a place where you left your

```
/*
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });*/
```

You could do it this way:

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "ar" ] );
  });
```

#datepicker - is a reference to your

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

It means "the Dom element with id="datepicker""

That should be it.

Comment: This solution change name of datepicker texts If we need to get hijri date from datepicker What to do?